# How to obtain user input on a clock interface

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, clock

We would like to capture the user input pertaining to the hour & minute hands on a clock. What kind of clock interfaces are available to achieve this?

(e.g. select 9.30 AM on the clock or select 3.45 PM on the clock)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have some of the best I've seen:

http://www.codigomanso.com/es/2008/12/recopilacion-de-time-pickers-con-javascript/